# typescript: how to declare function rturn type that inside of object

Tags: typescript

I'm creating an error object that conatains multiple errors that return type of IErrorForm. but if I focus on a function and set the return type of IErrorFunc, an error occurs in an object such as PermissionDenied and conversely, if I focus on the object and set the return type of IErrorObj, an error occurs in the function.

So if I use union type like below, the error occurs in a function. the error message is

'Type (from: string) => { sucess: boolean; code: number; message: string; }'does not have properties sucess, code, message of type '{ sucess: boolean; code: number; message: string; }'. ts(2739)

How can i declare return types of object?

```js
type IErrorForm = {
  sucess: boolean;
  code: number;
  message: string;
};
type IErrorsFunc = {
  (...args: any[]): {
    sucess: boolean;
    code: number;
    message: string;
  };
};

interface IErrorObj {
  [key: string]: { sucess: boolean; code: number; message: string };
}

export const CommonErrors: (IErrorObj | IErrorsFunc) = {
  unexpectedError(from: string) {
    return {
      sucess: false,
      code: 101,
      message: `Unexpected error from ${from}`,
    };
  },
  NotFound(object: string): IErrorForm {
    return {
      sucess: false,
      code: 102,
      message: `${object} not found`,
    };
  },
  permissionDenied: {
    sucess: false,
    code: 103,
    message: 'Permission denied: do not have permission.',
  },
  accessDenied(message: string): IErrorForm {
    return {
      sucess: false,
      code: 104,
      message: `Access denied: ${message}`,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: The wording of your question is confusing me, so I'm not sure.  But is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgXllN) what you're trying to do? If so, I could possibly write up an answer.  If not, could you clarify your intent?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry i'm late and yes! that's what i'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Answered; note that the word "success" has two "c"s in it.

Comment: @jcalz lol. I'm out of it today. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your intent is for `CommonErrors` to be an object with arbitrary keys, and whose values are *either* `IErrorForm` *or* `IErrorsFunc`.  If we call that type `IErrorObj`, then it looks like:

```
interface IErrorObj {
  [key: string]: IErrorForm | IErrorsFunc;
}
```

with a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to give us the arbitrary keys, and the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `IErrorForm` and `IErrorsFunc` to give us the either/or behavior.

If we do that, then your code compiles with no error:

```
export const CommonErrors: IErrorObj = {
  unexpectedError(from: string) {
    return {
      success: false,
      code: 101,
      message: `Unexpected error from ${from}`,
    };
  },
  NotFound(object: string): IErrorForm {
    return {
      success: false,
      code: 102,
      message: `${object} not found`,
    };
  },
  permissionDenied: {
    success: false,
    code: 103,
    message: 'Permission denied: do not have permission.',
  },
  accessDenied(message: string): IErrorForm {
    return {
      success: false,
      code: 104,
      message: `Access denied: ${message}`,
    };
  },
};
```

It's also noteworthy that the return type of `IErrorsFunc` has the same shape as `IErrorForm`, which means that we can just reuse that type name due to [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system).  So your final set of types can look like:

```
interface IErrorForm {
  success: boolean;
  code: number;
  message: string;
}

interface IErrorsFunc {
  (...args: any[]): IErrorForm
}

interface IErrorObj {
  [key: string]: IErrorForm | IErrorsFunc;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEpQPZQGK4C2yA3gFDLIDOArgklVQFzIBG22ANhHCANwVkCbABMILEDUKtoAyoQiM4Ac3HUwUUMoEBfMmVCRYiFBiy4qeGiASlBACgB0zuFGXNkvAJ4BtALoAlCxmOPhEZHoG4NDwSGiYoQDyrABWdpQ+ANYQXixUGlp+wQm4BFDEAD7x5lCW1gi6+hAAHgAOuGBC2CD5yADC2ISE3SW1xTXJaQC86cjWLa0QCJAio-YwOIR5BSDKAbOUUBBgNFAgB5TUdAwe8JxUEAA0gpddYiwAjAAMH8+v8ooqCo1AADACqIAWSxWyGgoWQG0GyAAJCREYQdCC-pcdHJkDpsQA5bBgAjWET2bCpaHbTS7ILVUJlYjkV5HE5nC6UWj0QEsO4PbGvYTvZDfABMQsuCiUqhYINRVJS0J0yBAJIR2HJWJe+LxBMEi3KwEYwG6ABEICBgBARCxWZceTd+XB7k9dSK1N8AMxSmVAuXIADkAAVoIQTVQzecxNbbSwRNg1RqABZwABuKCNEdN3UcQexBsoiBulrjFP9wNpWgZIVKRAu7NO5wdrydfIRrsFusons+XwALFKAbLQQBBXmMZCxm12lEkSuqTFS3GCA2roA)

Comment: thanks. thank! But I ran into another problem. When I try to use a Common Error object like CommonError.notFound('user'), i keep getting an same error. error message: This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'IErrorReturn | IErrorsFunc' are callable. Type 'IErrorReturn' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: I'm happy to help but that's out of scope for the question. You annotated `CommonErrors` as a type where the compiler does not know if each property is a plain object or a function.  You should probably not annotate at all, just `const CommonErrors =` instead of `const CommonErrors: IErrorObj = `.  If you must annotate, then you'll need a runtime test to distinguish between function properties and plain object properties.  Comment sections are insufficient to explain this, so if you still need more assistance you might want to make a new post (after searching for duplicates). Good luck!

Comment: It hard... thank you for your help!